Samba wastes a lot of time with permission checks
I'm running a samba server on a DIY NAS at home. Some applications on Windows client PCs seem to trigger odd behaviour: Samba wastes a lot of time seemingly doing permission checks on various directories, trying the same things over and over. This makes even simple file operations take several seconds, as thousands of checks are performed, rendering affected applications very laggy and sluggish.
Here's what a typical strace excerpt looks like, except this repeats hundreds of times within tenths of a second:
19:31:11.849408 chdir("/mnt/8t3")       = 0 <0.000009>
19:31:11.849440 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0770, st_size=102, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000020>
19:31:11.849500 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/8t3", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0770, st_size=102, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000036>
19:31:11.849578 getxattr("/proc/self/fd/38", "user.DOSATTRIB", 0x7fff4f6c9920, 256) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.000015>
19:31:11.849677 fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28046978, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.849704 close(38)               = 0 <0.000007>
19:31:11.849734 sendmsg(69, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0\0\0|", iov_len=4}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov
19:31:11.849786 epoll_wait(5, [{events=EPOLLIN, data={u32=1470646528, u64=107899639056640}}], 1, 9914) = 1 <0.000602>
19:31:11.850453 recvmsg(36, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0\0\1t", iov_len=4}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0,
19:31:11.850535 recvmsg(36, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\376SMB@\0\1\0002\0\0\0\5\0\0\0000\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\25x\3
19:31:11.850572 recvmsg(36, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\300\0\0\0\264\0\0\0A\0r\0c\0h\0i\0v\0e\0\\\0p\0h\0o\0
19:31:11.850623 openat2(AT_FDCWD, "Archive/photo/2024-06", {flags=O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_PATH, resolve=RESOLVE_NO_SYMLINKS}, 24) = 30
19:31:11.850663 fstat(30, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=7808, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.850692 openat(30, "_DSC1351.NEF", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_PATH) = 38 <0.000009>
19:31:11.850723 fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28002636, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.850761 getxattr("/proc/self/fd/38", "user.DOSATTRIB", 0x7fff4f6c9260, 256) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.000014>
19:31:11.850800 fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28002636, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.850826 getxattr("/proc/self/fd/38", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fff4f6c8f00, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.0000
19:31:11.850856 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd/38", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28002636, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000008>
19:31:11.850894 getpid()                = 1853067 <0.000005>
19:31:11.850915 getpid()                = 1853067 <0.000005>
19:31:11.850941 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/samba/winbindd", 0x7fff4f6c5470, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directo
19:31:11.850972 geteuid()               = 1000 <0.000008>
19:31:11.851004 getegid()               = 1000 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851031 getgroups(0, NULL)      = 9 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851061 getgroups(9, [4, 5, 10, 33, 91, 95, 98, 100, 1000]) = 9 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851086 geteuid()               = 1000 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851105 setresuid(0, 0, -1)     = 0 <0.000008>
19:31:11.851127 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851146 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851167 getegid()               = 1000 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851187 setresgid(-1, 0, -1)    = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851209 getegid()               = 0 <0.000007>
19:31:11.851232 getegid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851253 setgroups(0, NULL)      = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851274 setresgid(-1, 0, -1)    = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851296 getegid()               = 0 <0.000009>
19:31:11.851326 setresuid(0, 0, -1)     = 0 <0.000009>
19:31:11.851356 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000008>
19:31:11.851385 fcntl(25, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=168, l_len=1}) = 0 <0.000009>
19:31:11.851420 fcntl(25, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_UNLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=168, l_len=1}) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851449 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851471 getegid()               = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851492 setgroups(9, [1000, 4, 5, 10, 33, 91, 95, 98, 100]) = 0 <0.000007>
19:31:11.851520 setresgid(-1, 1000, -1) = 0 <0.000007>
19:31:11.851543 getegid()               = 1000 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851564 setresuid(1000, 1000, -1) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851586 geteuid()               = 1000 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851626 getxattr("/proc/self/fd/38", "user.DOSATTRIB", 0x7fff4f6c96c0, 256) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.000012>
19:31:11.851662 fstat(38, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28002636, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851689 getxattr("/proc/self/fd/38", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fff4f6c9390, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.0000
19:31:11.851719 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd/38", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=28002636, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000010>
19:31:11.851765 getpid()                = 1853067 <0.000008>
19:31:11.851796 getpid()                = 1853067 <0.000007>
19:31:11.851830 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/samba/winbindd", 0x7fff4f6c5900, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directo
19:31:11.851868 geteuid()               = 1000 <0.000008>
19:31:11.851899 getegid()               = 1000 <0.000009>
19:31:11.851934 getgroups(0, NULL)      = 9 <0.000006>
19:31:11.851958 getgroups(9, [4, 5, 10, 33, 91, 95, 98, 100, 1000]) = 9 <0.000005>
19:31:11.851986 geteuid()               = 1000 <0.000006>
19:31:11.852008 setresuid(0, 0, -1)     = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.852031 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852053 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.852076 getegid()               = 1000 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852097 setresgid(-1, 0, -1)    = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.852119 getegid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852138 getegid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852160 setgroups(0, NULL)      = 0 <0.000006>
19:31:11.852183 setresgid(-1, 0, -1)    = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852203 getegid()               = 0 <0.000005>
19:31:11.852223 setresuid(0, 0, -1)     = 0 <0.000005>

I'm not quite sure what triggers it. It seems to depend on the application. For affected applications readdir and close syscalls seem the most affected. Some of this seems to be transmitted back and forth between client and server as I can see about 1 Mbit/s up- and download while this is happening.
Restarting samba sometimes solves the problem for some time, demonstrating that this is some kind of misbehaviour.
I've tried disabling DOS attribute mappings, but this only brought a marginal improvement. It only seems to skip the getxattr(..., "user.DOSATTRIB", ...) call of the above. On the other hand it made system files like Thumbs.db visible, which I count as a disadvantage.
I've tried disabling Oplocks, but this brought no change.
My smb.conf looks like this (most comments removed for brevity):
[global]
smbd profiling level = off
# log level = 3

lock directory = /run/samba/lock
state directory = /var/cache/samba
cache directory = /run/samba/cache

workgroup = WORKGROUP

server string = CobraNAS
netbios name = CobraNAS

hosts allow = 192.168. 127.

printcap name = /etc/printcap
load printers = no

guest account = nobody

log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log

max log size = 50

security = user

username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins

dns proxy = no 

create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0775

acl allow execute always = true

force unknown acl user = yes

allow insecure wide links = yes

socket options = SO_KEEPALIVE TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072 TCP_KEEPIDLE=60 TCP_KEEPCNT=3 TCP_KEEPINTVL=3
deadtime = 15
server min protocol = SMB2_10

min receivefile size = 1
use sendfile = true

aio max threads = 32
aio read size = 1
aio write size = 1
#aio max threads = 100
#aio write behind = /
#strict allocate = yes
#write cache size = 262144
read raw = yes
write raw = yes
server signing = no
strict locking = no
getwd cache = yes
#oplocks = no
#kernel oplocks = yes
#max xmit = 12288

#store dos attributes = no
#ea support = no
#map archive = no
#map hidden = no
#map readonly = no
#map system = no
#map acl inherit = no

# multi channel support required for RSS. Add speed hints to avoid unnecessary use of the 1G or VPN link.
server multi channel support = yes
interfaces = "192.168.16.2;capability=RSS,speed=10000000000" "192.168.0.100;capability=RSS,speed=1000000000" "192.168.77.18;speed=100000000"

# snip [homes] and some other shares

[8t3]
    invalid users = nobody
    guest ok = no
    comment = "8t3"
    path = /mnt/8t3
    valid users = cobra,Cobra_Fast,@users
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.0. 192.168.16. 127.
    hosts deny = 192.168.77.
    vfs objects = io_uring
#   nt acl support = no

Samba 4.20.2 on Arch. Underlying filesystem is btrfs. Capable hardware (Intel i7, 10G link).
How do I make Samba stop this wasteful behaviour to restore good performance on affected applications?

Does the use of speed disable autonegotiation?  If so, get rid of it.  1000BaseT and higher require autonegotiation, and if you have a link that won't autonegotiate its proper speed, something is wrong.  If a wheel falls off your car you don't nail it to the axle and try to keep driving, do you?  Well, that's what disabling autonegotiation is doing to network links.

@AndrewHenle speed doesn't set the speed, it tells Samba what the speed is. The two NICs have negotiated 10Gbps and 1Gbps respectively, but without the speed hint Samba will treat them as equal and split traffic between them which in turn results in worse performance than only using the 10Gbps link. In any case, I don't think it has any weight on the problem I'm actually trying to solve here.

Thanks for the fast clarification.  I asked because I've seen disabled autonegotiation result in a delayed drop in performance - when the load on a switch got high enough to hit a bad DIMM on that switch, links with disabled autonegotiation using jumbo frames pretty much crapped out, but standard-compliant links didn't care.  Your question doesn't clearly state that the permissions checks don't happen when performance is good, so they might not be the cause of your problems.
